# what does "active" mean to linux timer?

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, driver, kernel-module

When I use add_timer&del_timer on linux kernel developing, the words "active", "inactive" and "deactivate" are often shown in function usage explanation. What does "active" mean ?

Does it mean: The time of which the value is assigned to timer_list->expires is reached, so the timer is active. Or does it mean that the timer is active immediately after add_timer or mod_timer is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An inactive timer won't fire. You can activate it with `mod_timer`. Deactivating is possible with `del_timer`.

Comment: Do you mean that the timer is activated by mod_timer or add_timer function only, and the timer is inactive when the deadline is reached or modified by del_timer ?  @a3f

Comment: @river Exactly.